# can't get back into ubuntu 14.04 LTS/xfce4 after x.org update - known conflict x.org & xbmc

Tags: updates, xorg, intel-graphics, xfce, xbmc

I'm sorry to report, I'm afraid I have inadvertently borked my Ubuntu install up, pretty good this time. I cannot even get back in to alter or delete anything that might be causing the problem - it stops part way through start-up as it is loading the GLX (OpenGL) driver extension as part of x.org, every time, and I cannot get past that. I am hoping someone else here has seen this and can point me toward what to do.

**here's my set-up --**

I'm on an Acer laptop with Intel Celeron 2955U @ 1.40 GHz Dual-core, the Intel HD Graphics Controller, and i am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS (trusty tahr) with the xfce4 desktop.

Once it was running,Ii was so thrilled I went out and got all the current software updates with the Ubuntu update manager. The update manager then wanted me to restart for the updates to complete and I did so.

When I came back in and tried to run Ubuntu 14.04 with xfce4 again, I get the following -

```
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
```

I google searched the error `xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)` and it is discussed on this arch linux forum thread, **"[XBMC Not starting from systemd service unit after latest Xorg update](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185017)"** here and is a known issue since the last x.org update, detailed in this bug, here - **"[FS#41391 - [xbmc] Since the new xorg update, xbmc.service does not start.](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/41391)"** i specified i wanted xbmc in my ubuntu install. so when i ran the software update, it probably updated me to the latest x.org, which conflicts with xbmc. i suspect this is why, after i restarted, i probably what i ran into this error and can't get the ubuntu 14.04 with xfce4 back up.

I'm wondering what is to be done here, seeing how this is a known bug currently between the current update of x.org & xbmc? is there some way to do edit some configuration file, somewhere, and take out just the xbmc so ubuntu will run again? or maybe edit something associated with the Intel GLX drivers? the thing is, i've google searched and done numerous grep and find searches, and can't find where the configuration files for those drivers are located on my install. or is this just an unfortunate whole re-install of my ubuntu with xfce4 (i hope not - that would really bum me out)? i can't get back into linux to edit or update anything else that might fix it, as it halts at that line above ^^^^ while starting up.

here's my `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` on this --

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.1.log
[ 13227.500] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[ 13227.500] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 13227.500] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[ 13227.502] Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Mon Sep 22 22:24:39 PDT 2014 x86_64
[ 13227.502] Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=bded8a61-c339-fa4d-8eec-1af166cf4e3d/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=bded8a61-c339-fa4d-8eec-1af166cf4e3d/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=1723ace42f755a5abb3bfb7cf61a0d67ad5dc2f5 salt=e138e8722be4473d6e257fa288cb7da65763aa2652571dafc68502f83dd65344" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=bded8a61-c339-fa4d-8eec-1af166cf4e3d add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic iTCO_vendor_support.vendorsupport=3 
[ 13227.504] Build Date: 30 July 2014  12:21:54AM
[ 13227.504] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[ 13227.504] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[ 13227.504]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 13227.504] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 13227.505] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Sat Oct 11 22:36:20 2014
[ 13227.512] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 13227.534] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 13227.534] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 13227.534] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 13227.534] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 13227.534] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 13227.534] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 13227.534] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 13227.534] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 13227.541] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 13227.541]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 13227.541] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[ 13227.541]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 13227.541] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 13227.541]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 13227.542] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[ 13227.542]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 13227.542] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 13227.542]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 13227.542] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[ 13227.542] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 13227.542] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 13227.542] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f0352dd6d40
[ 13227.542] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 13227.542]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 13227.542]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[ 13227.542]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[ 13227.542]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[ 13227.542] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 13227.543] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0a06:1025:0a11 rev 9, Mem @ 0xe0000000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00001800/64
[ 13227.545] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[ 13227.545] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[ 13227.545] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[ 13227.545] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[ 13227.545] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[ 13227.545] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[ 13227.545] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[ 13227.545] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension Present
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[ 13227.546] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[ 13227.546] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 13227.554] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 13227.644] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 13227.644]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[ 13227.644]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[ 13227.644] (==) AIGLX enabled
[ 13227.644] Loading extension GLX
[ 13227.644] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 13227.644] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 13227.644] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 13227.644] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[ 13227.644] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[ 13227.644] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 13227.644] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[ 13227.650] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[ 13227.688] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 13227.688]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.910
[ 13227.688]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 13227.688]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 13227.688] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 13227.689] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 13227.696] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 13227.696]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[ 13227.696]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 13227.696]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 13227.696] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[ 13227.696] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 13227.700] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 13227.700]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[ 13227.700]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 13227.700]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 13227.700] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[ 13227.700] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[ 13227.704] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 13227.704]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[ 13227.704]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 13227.704]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 13227.704] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
        i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
        915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
        Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
        GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[ 13227.709] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[ 13227.709] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[ 13227.709] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[ 13227.709] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 13227.709] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 13227.709] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[ 13227.709] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 13227.709] (EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
[ 13227.709] (EE) 
[ 13227.709] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 13227.709] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[ 13227.709] (EE)
```

Comment: Try opeing a console with ctrl + alt + F1, and uninstall the conflicting package with `sudo apt-get purge packagename`. Check what this would uninstall before accepting. If it says it will uninstall 100 packages, cancel the operation.

Comment: hello - thank you for responding. unfortunately, i cannot get to a terminal. the operation i printed the log from above, in my original query, takes just a few seconds and is the opening lines of ubuntu with xfce4 loading. it is loading the opening x.org video drivers, in particular, and quits being unable to proceed further. so it never really starts up, is done in seconds, and i cannot get to a terminal. any other possible suggests? if someone could tell me where the *.conf files are for xbmc  or, in particular, the Intel HD Graphics video drivers are, i could go edit those to get around it.

Comment: Try booting in recovery mode, mount the Ubuntu partition r/w, then try this solution "I confirm just adding a file /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config with one line "allowed_users = anybody" fixes the problem." Source: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/41391

Comment: hi @ToDo - thank you again. that would work, if i were further along in the process. i hold down the shift key, but if you look at the logs i posted above, it's the early loading drivers. i hold down shift, nothing happens, it goes through loading the drivers and fails on the intel/GLX drivers. so i'm afraid that doesn't help, but thank you. again, if anyone could point me where the *.conf files are located in X11 for GLX and the intel hd graphics drivers, i can get to those, as it's on an external drive, and edit them and perhaps get this working. thank you again, in any case.

Comment: also @ToDo - i had all ready seen that referenced https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/41391 report and reference it and the forum post that links to it in my first post above ^^^^. i all ready checked my `/etc/X11/xwrapper.confg` and it all ready has the line `allowed_users=anybody` in there. so i don't know what else to do at this point.

Comment: Your last chance would be to boot from a liveUSB and modify any files manually. If you know what to modify, that is. If not, it may be quicker to backup your files and reinstall the system.

Comment: @ToDo - yeah, unfortunately, it looks like that's what i'll have to do. i'm waiting on an ebay delivery of a new external device to do that with, then i'll format it and start again. this time _without_ xbmc, as to avoid its conflict with the current update of x.org. unless you can point me to which config. files, and where they are located, contain the references to the intel GLX drivers and/or xbmc and i can edit those references. if not, looks just like a standard BURF - back-up, reformat, re-install. i do thank you, in any case, for all your help.